# Changing size of exponent

Tags: equations, amsmath

When I write exponential function like

[image]

where the size of exponential function becomes tiny compared to other math equation. How can I match the size?

Comment: I suggest you use `\exp(...)` instead of `e^{...}`.

Comment: I want to stick to e^{...}. Any suggetion?

Comment: Sticking to `e^{...}` and getting a larger size of superscript would violate the normal display rule. If you insist that instead of `\exp`, you may use `\displaystyle` to enlarge the exponential.

Comment: You could use `e^{\displaystyle{...}}` but it really won't look good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Bad: \verb`e^{...}`
\begin{align*}
Z(\lambda)&=\sum_{N_+=0}^{\infty}\sum_{N_-=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_c^{N_+}\lambda_a^{N_-}}{N_+!N_-!}Z\\
&=\int\mathcal{D}\phi_e(r)e^{
-\frac{\beta_e}{2}\int dr(\nabla\phi_e(r))^2-\mathrm{i}\beta\int dr\phi_e(r)\rho_f(r)
}
\end{align*}
Better: \verb`\exp\Bigl(...\Bigr)`
\begin{align*}
Z(\lambda)&=\sum_{N_+=0}^{\infty}\sum_{N_-=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_c^{N_+}\lambda_a^{N_-}}{N_+!N_-!}Z\\
&=\int\mathcal{D}\phi_e(r)\exp\Bigl(
-\frac{\beta_e}{2}\int dr(\nabla\phi_e(r))^2-\mathrm{i}\beta\int dr\phi_e(r)\rho_f(r)
\Bigr)
\end{align*}
Maybe: \verb`e^{\displaystyle{...}}`
\begin{align*}
Z(\lambda)&=\sum_{N_+=0}^{\infty}\sum_{N_-=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_c^{N_+}\lambda_a^{N_-}}{N_+!N_-!}Z\\
&=\int\mathcal{D}\phi_e(r)e^{\displaystyle{
-\frac{\beta_e}{2}\int dr(\nabla\phi_e(r))^2-\mathrm{i}\beta\int dr\phi_e(r)\rho_f(r)
}}
\end{align*}
Another option:
\begin{align*}
Z(\lambda)&=\sum_{N_+=0}^{\infty}\sum_{N_-=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_c^{N_+}\lambda_a^{N_-}}{N_+!N_-!}Z\\
&=\int\mathcal{D}\phi_e(r)e^K,
\end{align*}
where $K=-\frac{\beta_e}{2}\int dr(\nabla\phi_e(r))^2-\mathrm{i}\beta\int dr\phi_e(r)\rho_f(r)$.

\end{document}
```